# python math, How do I get 2 full box and 9 partial on my apples problems

Tags: python, math

lets say I have 29 apples and put them in boxes where I can fit 10 apples in each box.
when I do print statement I want to see
print(apple)
1 (Full)
2 (Full)
9 (EA)

have any idea how my code should be?

I tried using

```
full = 10
qty = 29
fullboxes = math.ceil(qty/full)
partials = qty-fullboxes
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: Use [Edit] to add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `divmod` to get the number of full boxes and the remainder. The rest is just printing.

```
apples = 29
boxsize = 10

a,b = divmod(apples, boxsize)
for i in range(a):
    print(f'{i+1} (Full)', end=' ')
if b:
    print(f'{b} (EA)')
```

output: `1 (Full) 2 (Full) 9 (EA)`

output for 30 apples: `1 (Full) 2 (Full) 3 (Full)`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here but
the following code will do what you have described.

```
d = 29
j = divmod(d, 10)
for i in range(j[0]):
   print(f'({i + 1}(full)', end=' ')
else:
   print(f'{j[1]}(EA)')
```

The function `divmod(x, y)` takes two arguments x and y and gives a tuple of their quotient and remainder.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_divmod.asp)